# Website Login using Powershell - Click method missing

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automate the way I login to my amazon account. Currently, I'm stuck on not being able to automate left-click on continue button after entering username.

```
#Here's my code:
$username = "1@2.com" 
$password = "test123" 
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin") 

while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -seconds 5 }

($ie.document.getElementById("ap_email") |select -first 1).value = $username
Start-Sleep -seconds 5

while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -seconds 5 }

$continueButton = $ie.document.getElementById("continue").Click()

Write-Output Script_Complete.
pause

$ie.quit()
```

Comment: I don't even see click() as an available method in System.__ComObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
$username = "username" 
$password = "password" 
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://login.amazon.com/agreement") 

while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -seconds 2 }

($ie.document.getElementById("ap_email") |select -first 1).value = $username
($ie.document.getElementById("ap_password") |select -first 1).value = $password

while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -seconds 2 }


$continueButton = $ie.document.getElementById("signInSubmit")
$continueButton.Click()

Write-Output Script_Complete.
pause

$ie.quit()
```